# HTML only renders when text is outside DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css

If I simply go to a page on my server the html that is rendered has no style, even though the files are included and are found(no errors). If I place at least one character of text above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` it renders perfectly. This is weird is there any way to get the page to render without the text I add above the `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

before I add the text:

[image]

after the text. The arrow is pointing to the period I added outside the `<!DOCTYPE html>` this can be any length of text:

[image]

here is the top of the html on the before:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

here is the top of the html on the after:

```
.
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: The actual code would be useful here.

Comment: Can you replicate on multiple browsers?

Comment: Are you able to update with a link to your site?

Comment: What character encoding is the file saved with and what is it being served as by the web server? (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-8 without BOM, ANSI, etc.) It's difficult to say what the issue is without being able to see the page itself.

Comment: Show a real example that reproduces the issue. The problem is probably in your CSS, which is all broken (violates CSS specs) but gets applied in Quirks Mode. And the question does not now say anything about the CSS code.